# How to select non zero rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using MS SQL Server.
I have 20 columns in total in my table out of which 10 are varchar, 10 are int.
I have to fetch all the rows wherein I have any non-zero values in those 10 int rows ( say p1 to p10)

I have made the following query

```
select * from table_name where exists (select * from table_name where p1 > 0)
```

I want to select p1 to p10 columns with values greater than 0 ( in any of them ).
This query returns all the rows. I am unable to find a way around this.

Comment: You need to choose between "any non-zero values" and "values greater than 0". Do you want a row returned if the value `-42` is encountered?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
where p1 > 0 OR p2 > 0 OR ... OR p10 > 0
```

or

```
select * 
from table_name 
where COALESCE(p1, p2, ... ,p10) > 0
```

Also, if interested, your query is not working as you want, as you are telling the engine to do different thing. You are saying:

1. give me all rows

   ```
   select * from table_name T1
   ```
2. if the condition is true - and the condition is, is there a row in the table (and there is at least one row)

   ```
   where exists 
   (
       select * from table_name T2 where T2.p1 > 0
   )
   ```

if you want do use exists, you need to eval such condition for each row:

```
select * from table_name T1
where exists 
(
    select * 
    from table_name T2 
    where T2.p1 > 0
        AND T1.[id] = T2.[id]
)
```

but it's a kind of overkill in this case.

Comment: Thank you @gotqn , using COALESCE worked. Thanks for the explanation too, understood where I went wrong :)

Comment: @Sca . . . The first version should work.  The `COALESCE()` version is not guaranteed to work, because there could be an explicit `0` before a positive value.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach considering NULLIF. If equal to 0, we are considering it as null.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(p1 int, p2 int, p3 int, 
p4 int, p5 int,p6 int, p7 int,p8 int, p9 int, p10 int)

insert into @table
VALUES
(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),
(1,1,1,0,null,null,1,1,1,1),
(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT
NULLIF(p1,0) as p1
,NULLIF(p2,0) as p2
,NULLIF(p3,0) as p3
,NULLIF(p4,0) as p4
,NULLIF(p5,0) as p5
,NULLIF(p6,0) as p6
,NULLIF(p7,0) as p7
,NULLIF(p8,0) as p8
,NULLIF(p9,0) as p9
,NULLIF(p10,0) as p10
from @table) as t
WHERE p1 is not null 
or p2 is not null
or p3 is not null
or p4 is not null
or p5 is not null
or p6 is not null
or p7 is not null
or p8 is not null
or p9 is not null
or p10 is not null
```

```
+----+----+----+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----+
| p1 | p2 | p3 |  p4  |  p5  |  p6  | p7 | p8 | p9 | p10 |
+----+----+----+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----+
|  1 |  1 |  1 | 1    | 1    | 1    |  1 |  1 |  1 |   1 |
|  1 |  1 |  1 | NULL | 1    | 1    |  1 |  1 |  1 |   1 |
|  1 |  1 |  1 | NULL | NULL | NULL |  1 |  1 |  1 |   1 |
+----+----+----+------+------+------+----+----+----+-----+
```